# GET: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR nginx + vue.js

Tags: vue.js, ssl, nginx, webpack, ubuntu-18.04

In console log of Google Chrome I'm getting these errors :

```
GET https://192.168.1.7:8081/sockjs-node/info?t=1579798623564 net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
GET https://192.168.1.7/sockjs-node/info?t=1579798623562 net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

[image]

if in /etc/nginx/conf/default.conf   ( Ubuntu 18.04.03 Server Edition):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/chained.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domain.key;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/chained.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domain.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.7:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.7:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

I setup vue.config.js as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false,
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      enableInSFC: true
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    host: '192.168.1.7',
    hot: true,
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
}
```

and defined webpack.config.js as follows :

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    https: {
        key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/domain.key'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/chained.pem')
    }
};
```

Update 1)

Modifying in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf http -> https:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://192.168.1.7:8081;
```

leads to 502 Bad Gateway :
[image]

So... my question is now: how to make the nginx server answer with TLS?

What am I doing wrongly? How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
GET https://192.168.1.7:8081/sockjs-node/info?t=1579798623564 net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
 ...
proxy_pass http://192.168.1.7:8081;
```

In the nginx configuration you access `192.168.1.7:8081` as `http://`. In the first line you access the same IP:port with `https://` which results in a protocol error. While nothing is known about the server on this IP:port it is very likely that is only `http://` which would explain the protocol error: attempt to do a TLS handshake against a server which does not answer with TLS.

```
GET https://192.168.1.7/sockjs-node/info?t=1579798623562 net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

Nothing is known about the certificate on `192.168.1.7:443` (443 is default port for https) but very likely this certificate does not contain `192.168.1.7` as a valid IP SAN. But this is the expected value for certificate verification when using the URL `https://192.168.1.7/`.

Comment: It is indeed, thank for pointing at it, a mismatch between the location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.7:8081;  in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf and the fact that in browser I'm using https. Do I need to modify in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf to https://192.168.1.7:8081 ?

Comment: I updated my post with update 1. my question is now: how to make the nginx server answer with TLS?. Regarding the certificate, I actually do not remember how it was made and if, probably not, contains 192.168.1.7. What's the best way to renew the certificate?

Comment: @user2315094: This was the wrong fix. You broke the working part and kept the broken part broken.

Comment: I integrated my initial question with the complete /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file. I thought that with that nginx configuration the server should have responded with TLS. But, it seems that is not definitely the case... So... how to make the server answer with TLS? And how to correctly renew the certificates?

Comment: @user2315094: Your server at port 443 already did answer with TLS  but the certificate did not match the domain of the URL. As for the webpack part see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhttps and note that you are not giving a certificate, only key and ca.

Comment: So the required steps I need to take to solve all these problems are: 1) renew the domain certificate 2) put these renewed domain certificates in /etc/nginx/conf/default.conf 3) put these renewed domain certificates in webpack.config.js . Is it correct? If this process to fix everything is correct, I think it's better if I anticipate renew my domain certificates, with Let's Encrypt service, as soon as possible

Comment: Do you think that the certificates issuing process here, https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh , is the correct one for my peculiar purposes?

Comment: @user2315094: Renewing is extending the life time of a certificate. This is about the name in the certificate not matching the URL.Renewing will not help here but you need to a different certificate with a matching name or you need to use a URL matching the certificate. See [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity) to get an understanding of the concepts involved.

Comment: I checked with DigiCert's tool my present certificate. This is the result:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=11-O73kNwAwSkZyA2bhlJJRVB5fYDPZI7   . If it's a matching problem, how to use a URL matching the certificate (second option)? But. may be the first option, getting a different certificate with a matching name, is viable too... but how to get it?

Comment: @user2315094: You are using an internal IP address in the URL to access a certificate which has a public domain name. If this is because the domain does not map to the IP address of your (test) server you have to add a manual mapping - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687372/how-can-i-ensure-ssl-was-installed-correctly-before-changing-dnst

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206574/discussion-between-user2315094-and-steffen-ullrich).

Comment: So I am still not sure how to fix this